# How to make a custom Drain Skill spell for training?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iii-morrowind

I made a couple of custom Drain Skill spells in order to train cheaper most of my skills. For example:

```
Trainer 1
Drain Short Sword 100 pt on self for 2 seconds
Drain Marksman 100 pt on self for 2 seconds
Drain Sneak 100 pt on self for 2 seconds
Drain Security 100 pt on self for 2 seconds
```

However this doesn't seems to work. In House Halalu on Balmora one of the trainers charges me with 239 gold for training Security, so I cast the spell and when I ask again for training he still charges me with 239 gold! And my skills are effectively on 0. What I am doing wrong? In Elder Scrolls Oblivion I used to train this way and always worked. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice to close voters: creating weird spells like this is part of morrowind's gameplay, and is not a game design question.

Comment: It's been a while, but I think you need to use Damage in Morrowind to affect trainers.  It's been a LONG time though...

Comment: Hmm, well, looks like the [Drain Skill](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Drain_Skill) effect is suppose to do this.  I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: Well not a real answer, but Morrowind's alchemy system is pretty OP and you can easily make super potions in 20 minutes.

Comment: @Nelson I am aware about alchemy, I am making super potions AF and getting lots of septims. But I've read about this "exploit" and I wanted to give it a try. In TES: Oblivion it worked like a charm, but is not working for me on Morrowind

Comment: Dou you have `OpenMW` installed?

Comment: @AntiDrondert no I don't

Answer (score 1):

According to the UESP wiki, your method should work: https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Trainers

> You can reduce training costs to 1gp per level by creating a spell or enchantment of **Drain Skill** of 100 for 2-3 seconds

If it's not, then is it possible:

1. You're running some engine modifications, like the *Morrowind Code Patch*
2. You're running some mods, like *Morrowind Patch for Purists*

Some mods or engine modifications likely affect this behavior, since it's deemed "cheesy".

However, you do have other options that may help and might be worth trying in the meantime:

1: Fortify Merchantile 100 points 2-3 seconds

2: Raise the trainer's disposition to 100, using any method you like

Comment: I'll try this and let you know